# Pylint is not catching "Local variable 'xyz' might be referenced before assignment " but PyCharm is highlighing the same, using python 2.7

Tags: python, exception, pylint

```
        if goal:
            checkA = checkAfunc(user, goal)
            if not checkA:
                if goal:
                    xyz, _ = checkB(user, goal)
                else
                    xyz, _ = checkB(user, goal)
            checkA = xyz or checkA
```

While refactoring the above code, it got committed without throwing any exception.
pylint check is also not emitting any error
While pycharm also uses pylint , it shows - Local variable 'xyz' might be referenced before assignment.
What rule shall be further added in pylint config for emitting this exception before committing the code itself?

Comment: pylint checks for un-initialized variable , if  only it can be statically determined  for eg

Answer (score 1):

pylint reports for un-initialized/un-defined variable , if  only it can be statically so determined . for eg ,pylint will not warn for x being un-defined in the following piece of code (as it is pure static analysis tool)

```
y=10
if  y==4:
    x=5
print(x)
```

pycharm does not use pylint by default. You will have to specifically configure pylint to be used. pycharm has its own inbuilt checker, which seems to check for conditional paths too. pycharm will warn you

Comment: Can we use Pycharms lint checker via command line ?

Comment: Yes you can
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/command-line-code-inspector.html#options
I also checked it works.

Comment: To have pylint in pycharm you need to install `pylint-pycharm` https://github.com/leinardi/pylint-pycharm or set up pylint in pycharm https://stackoverflow.com/a/46409649/2519059